# C# Can I identify what Random selects between the range?

Tags: c#, random

I want to be able to determine what the value is selected when I get a random number in windows forms. 
For example, **int mynum = numbers[rand.Next(0,7)];**
I know the range is between 0 and 7, but I want to be able to identify what number is selected. e.g. numbers[3]

The following is the code I have.  I have read binary values into an array int [] numbers and passed it through the following method.  It generates my random 3 bit binary value, but I am making a small quiz where the number identified is the value the random number selects (e.g. the location 3 is the correct value for the item stored there, numbers[i] ==answer).

Is there a way to access this value?

```
public void generateBinary3bit(int[] numbers, Form1 f1)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int mynum = numbers[rand.Next(0,7)];

            **int ans = numbers[rand];** 

            f1.lblBinaryText.Text = mynum.ToString();
        }
```

For context, I am reading in the values into the array here:

```
int [] numbers = new int[8];

  public void readNumbers(int[]numbers, Form1 F1)
        {
            try
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\BinaryNumbers.csv");

                while(sr.ReadLine() !=null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
                    {
                        numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(sr.ReadLine());
                        answer = i;
                    }
                }
                sr.Close();
            }
            catch ( Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
```

Thank you,

Comment: I am very confused, do you want to know what number comes from the random generation?  You already have that, its `mynum`.  Also, dont instantiate a random in the method, create a shared static random so that you dont have seed collisions.  You might even consider using File.ReadAllLines instead of using StreamReader and a while loop

Comment: If you mean you want the index then just assign the result of `Next` to a variable before using it to access the value at that position in the array.  Also be careful of creating a `Random` object locally as you'll get duplicate random numbers if that method is used in a tight loop.

Comment: Change `int mynum = numbers[rand.Next(0,7)];` to `int index = rand.Next(0, 7); int mynum = numbers[index];`, now you have the index and the number from the array.

Comment: @Johnstonn is your end goal to get a random number from your text file, then convert that number into its 3 bit binary value?

Comment: Perfect @Blake Thingstad, that is exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Thanks for the advice regarding the loop mac

Comment: Another tip, I am assuming your array always has 7 values in it, which is why you chose `rand.Next(0, 7)`, but a better way to do this is `rand.Next(0, numbers.Length)`. That way if the length of the array ever changes, then you method already accommodates for it. If the array size already changes and you truly only every want one of the first 7 values, then disregard this.

Comment: @maccettura The goal was to generate a random 3 bit binary number (from a text file as I have 0-255 and have plans to make 4 bit randoms and 8 bit randoms too) and set up a basic quiz where it checks answers against the correct answer. 

The correct answer is the location value of the position in the text file, e.g. 0 is 00000000, 255 = 11111111 etc so my range of 0-7 is 000-111 giving me an easy way to assign the correct value for checking.

Comment: @BlakeThingstad I am chosing 7 so that it only reads between 000-111 for 3 bit as my array is actually 255 size and I only want to select random from a set range. (this is a basic quiz to help my students learn binary 3 bit, then 4 bit then 8 bit) difficulty levels.  I can select the levels with a range of the random (0-7 for 3 bit etc)

Comment: @Johnstonn why use the text file at all?  Just generate a random number between 0-255?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assign some variable to the result of the `rand.Next()` before using it in the array:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int randIndex = rand.Next(0,7);
int mynum = numbers[randIndex];
```

and you are good to go.